# PHP : Replace old domain from a html string

Tags: php

I have this html string, the domain inside the img tag is old and im trying to replace it using php.

```
<p align=center><img border=0 alt="" src="https://www.allstar.co.il/upload/editor/diagnostica.jpg" width=520 height=93></p>
```

expected output is :

```
<p align=center><img border=0 alt="" src="/upload/editor/diagnostica.jpg" width=520 height=93></p>
```

any possible soultion?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php ?

Comment: How is the [trim] tag relevant?

Comment: FYI, `trim()` is for removing characters from the beginning and end, not replacing in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

```
$catDescript = '<p align=center><img border=0 alt="" src="https://www.allstar.co.il/upload/editor/diagnostica.jpg" width=520 height=93></p>';
$domainNAME="https://www.allstar.co.il";
$newDesc = str_replace($domainNAME, "", $catDescript);
echo( $newDesc );
```

Comment: that works thats for the intent @0stone0